# #EU - Article 13 (Uploadfilter)

Tags: java, node.js, filter, socket.io, upload

Europe has agreed to Article 13 (upload filter).
This means that all content (images - texts) must be checked for copyright infringement before uploading. The platform is liable for the copyright infringement.

Startups (younger than 3 years, less than 10 million EUR turnover per year and less than 5 million users) are excluded.

My App in the App Store refers to user content (pictures and texts can be uploaded by the user).
My app exists longer than 3 years, therefore I am obliged to install an upload filter for copyright infringement.

Has anyone already know with it ? How can we as programmers best protect ourselves from warnings to be able to provide a good upload filter (Usage currently Java, NodeJS and Socket.IO)?

Thanks

Comment: How will stackoverlow handle this? No more code allowed?

Comment: @Ben No programming code and open source development stuff is excluded.

Comment: Some teams are working on that issue: https://framespot.com/